# filling numpy array with mean values form data

Tags: numpy, fill

Why does this produce an array of zeros for q, instead of the actualy value or err which is 0.0159?

```
errors=np.loadtxt('data').T[2]
err=np.mean(errors)
q=np.empty(99)
q.fill(err)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us enough code to reproduce the problem. Normally, `q.fill` would work as expected:

```
import numpy as np

err = 0.0159
q = np.empty(9)
q.fill(err)
print(q)
# [ 0.0159  0.0159  0.0159  0.0159  0.0159  0.0159  0.0159  0.0159  0.0159]
```

However, (taking a stab in the dark), *if `q` has an integer dtype*, then `q.fill(0.0159)` would floor 0.0159 down to the nearest int and thus `q` would become filled with zeros:

```
err = 0.0159
q = np.empty(9, dtype='int')
q.fill(err)
print(q)
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Hi, this is my fault when printing it only printed the values to 1 decimal place. making it 0.0. but the actual values in the array were correct